# HTML element parent-child relationship problem

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML. In my HTML code I have different sections. In my projects section I have 3 child sections but somehow my resume section header which is underneath my projects section and a separate section display as part of the projects section.
link to my repository: https://jobarkhuizen.github.io/FreeCodeCampPersonalPage/

I run my code through W3C validator and included the source, outline and clean up html in the run.  Validator run return no error and the outline shows that Projects and Resume sections are both children of the Body tag and Columns Tribute page, Landing page and Technical page are children of Projects section

```
<section id="projects">
    <h2><a id="portfolio">Projects</a></h2>
        <section id="col1"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Tribute Page</h3>
            <a href="https://jobarkhuizen.github.io/FCC_Tribute_Page/" target="_blank"> 
                <img class="project-tile" src="tributepage.jpg"  alt="Tribute Page Picture"></a>
                    <p>The following guidelines was provided for the tribute page.  It should have a div element with a corresponding id="img-div". Within the img-div element, there should be an img element with a 
                            corresponding id="image".  Within the img-div element, there should be an element with a corresponding id="img-caption" that contains textual
                            content describing the image shown in img-div.  There should be an element with a corresponding id="tribute-info", which contains textual content
                            describing the subject of the tribute page. Ther should be an a element with a corresponding id="tribute-link", which links to an outside site 
                            that contains additional information about the subject of the tribute page, this link must open in a new tab.  The img element should responsively
                            resize, relative to the width of its parent element, without exceeding its original size and should be centered within its parent element.
                            </p>
        </section>

    <section id="col2"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Landing Page</h3>
        <a href="https://jobarkhuizen.github.io/LandingPage/" target="_blank">
            <img class="project-tile" src="Landingp.jpg" alt="Landing Page Picture"></a> 
                <p>The following guidelines was provided for the product landing page. The page should have a header element with a corresponding id="header".
                        An image within the header element with a corresponding id="header-img".
                        Within the #header element a nav element with a corresponding id="nav-bar".
                        At least three clickable elements inside the nav element, each with the class nav-link.
                        When you click the nav-link button in the nav element, it goes to the corresponding section of the landing page.
                        Embed a watch-able video with id="video".
                        A form element with a corresponding id="form".  Within the form, there is an input field with id="email" where you can enter an email address.
                        The #email input field should have placeholder text to let the user know what the field is for and uses HTML5 validation to confirm text is correct.
                        Within the form, there is a submit input with a corresponding id="submit".</p> 
    </section>

    <section id="col3"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Technical Page</h3> 
        <a href="https://jobarkhuizen.github.io/FCC-Technical-Page/" target="_blank"> 
          <img class="project-tile" src="technicalp.jpg" alt="Technical Page Picture"></a>
                <p>The following guidelines was provided for the technical page. Should have a main element with a corresponding id="main-doc", which contains the page's main content.
                    Within the #main-doc element, you should have several section elements, each with a class of main-section.
                    The first element within each .main-section should be a header element which contains text that describes the topic of that section.
                    Each section element with the class of main-section should also have an id that corresponds with the text of each header contained within it. 
                    Any spaces should be replaced with underscores (id="Javascript_and_Java").
                    The .main-section elements should contain at least 10 p elements in total.
                    The .main-section elements should contain at least 5 code elements in total.
                    The .main-section elements should contain at least 5 li items in total. A nav element with a corresponding id="navbar".</p> 
    </section>
</section>

<section>
    <h2><a id="resume">Resume</a></h2>
        <p>Studying Responsive Web Design through FreeCodeCamp.  My next project is studying and completing JavaScript and SQL.</p>
        <p>I have done automated testing on Winrunner and QTP and managed projects through TestDirector.</p>
        <p>Did testing in both waterfall and agile development environments. </p>
        <p>This portfolio page is for Freecodecamp certification.  I have loaded a personal portfolio page on my Github account which I will update as soon as possible.</p>

</section>
```

The headings should have a brown background only and be center aligned, but my whole Projects section has a brown background and the Resume heading is on the right side of the page within the projects section

Comment: Theee may be other errors, but at forst glance, your image tags are not closes.

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. I think your main issue is the use of float property. This comes with many caveheats that are sometimes hard to grasp, even with valid code. If your goal using it is putting blocks besides each other, I would suggest to look at display:inline-block or even flexbox.

Comment: @DovRine this may not be a mistake but a feature if the OP is using HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use css [`float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float) property as `left`, then the content flows to the right of that element. This is unlike the normal flow of block elements which is vertically stacking one below another.

There are many ways to get around this, one way suggested in the spec is to use [`clear`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) as `both`:

> **both**: Requires that the top border edge of the box be below the bottom outer edge of any right-floating and left-floating boxes that
>   resulted from elements earlier in the source document.

So make your resume section as

```
<section class="resume">
</section>
```

and add its css as:

```
.resume {
    clear: both;
}
```

For the complete story refer [Visual Formatting Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#visual-model-intro)

Also, note that CSS has introduced a number of new features that we dont have to use `floats` for a column layout. We have `grid` and `flex` layouts for the same.

Comment: Thank you. Adding the class and setting style clear:both fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code
CSS

```
<pre>
    <style>
        .clear{clear:both;}
    </style>
    <section id="projects"> 
       ...
    </section>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</pre>
```